# Trying to test input validity

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, do-while

I've been working on a small project today, and after searching around for answers on StackOverflow and elsewhere, I've come to a roadblock.

I've been attempting to create a choose-your-own-adventure style game in Java and I'm beginning with creating a character using three characteristics (name, race, gender). I plan on using these to allow for branches in the story.

The problem is that I'm not getting the results I'm looking for. Currently, I've gotten my code to work, with a print statement showing the selections made by the player.

```
//list out character description

    System.out.println("You are " + Name + ", a " + characterGender + " " + 
    characterRace + ".");
```

I had it working properly until I attempted to implement a test on the input given to root out invalid entries. I've attempted to use do-while loops and try-catch statements, but it just runs forward to the next option regardless of whether or not there is a valid input.

The general idea I'm looking to implement is:

**display input options**

**check input to verify it is valid**

**if input is not valid, re-attempt to check for another input**

**if input is valid, move forward to next question**

```
//create test to verify validity of race selection

    boolean raceBoolean;

    if (raceInt < 0 || raceInt > 4) {

        raceBoolean = true;

    try {

        do {

    //selection list that defines options

                if (raceInt == 1)
                    characterRace = "human";

                else if (raceInt == 2)
                    characterRace = "elf";

                else if (raceInt == 3)
                    characterRace = "orc";

                else if (raceInt == 4)
                    characterRace = "undead";

        }

        while (raceBoolean = false);

            System.out.println("Nice try. Enter a valid number for one of the four races!");

        }

            finally {

        }
```

I'm honestly at a loss. I know that this is simple stuff, but I'm trying to teach myself. I appreciate any help that may be provided. Other topics aren't very helpful given that they don't provide much context for why there was an issue in the first place.

Thank you in advance. I'm honestly seeking to learn how to do this properly.

Full code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adventure {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //insert input tool
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create inventory object for gold and items
    int gold = 10;

    //create health points object 

    //address player with greeting
    System.out.println("Welcome to your adventure!");

    //ask for character name, race, and gender

    System.out.println("What will your adventurer's name be?");

    String Name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What will your adventurer's race be?");
    System.out.println("1. Human");
    System.out.println("2. Elf");
    System.out.println("3. Orc");
    System.out.println("4. Undead");

    int raceInt = input.nextInt();

    String characterRace = "";

    //create test to verify validity of race selection

    boolean raceBoolean;

    if (raceInt < 0 || raceInt > 4) {

        raceBoolean = true;

    try {

        do {

    //selection list that defines options

                if (raceInt == 1)
                    characterRace = "human";

                else if (raceInt == 2)
                    characterRace = "elf";

                else if (raceInt == 3)
                    characterRace = "orc";

                else if (raceInt == 4)
                    characterRace = "undead";

        }

        while (raceBoolean = false);

            System.out.println("Nice try. Enter a valid number for one of the four races!");

        }

            finally {

        }

    }

    //ask for character gender

    System.out.println("What will your adventurer's gender be?");
    System.out.println("1. Male");
    System.out.println("2. Female");

    int genderInt = input.nextInt();

    String characterGender = "";

    if (genderInt == 1)
        characterGender = "male";

    else if (genderInt == 2)
        characterGender = "female";

    //list out character description

    System.out.println("You are " + Name + ", a " + characterGender + " " + characterRace + ".");

    //introduce player to adventure with different introductions for different races

    System.out.print("You came to Glassolin with only ten gold pieces to your name. ");

    if (characterRace == "human")
        System.out.print("Glassolin is home to many humans; some from the far reaches of the realm. You feel right at home, more or less,"
                + " as long as you ignore the occasional odd look from the cityfolk staring at someone dressed in farmer's clothes.");
    else if (characterRace == "elf")
        System.out.print("While an elf isn't the most common sight around town, the locals seem like they don't care one way or another "
                + "about you wandering the streets. ");


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you had given  `while (raceBoolean=false)` (assignment operator) in comparison . And secondly were comparing string using `==` operator . But in java strings are compared using `.equals()` method. I have modified your code .

Here is the full working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //insert input tool
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create inventory object for gold and items
    int gold = 10;

    //create health points object 

    //address player with greeting
    System.out.println("Welcome to your adventure!");

    //ask for character name, race, and gender

    System.out.println("What will your adventurer's name be?");

    String Name = input.nextLine();



    //create test to verify validity of race selection

    boolean raceBoolean=true;
    String characterRace = "";



    try {

        do {

    //selection list that defines options
                                 System.out.println("What will your adventurer's race be?");
                                System.out.println("1. Human");
                                System.out.println("2. Elf");
                                System.out.println("3. Orc");
                                System.out.println("4. Undead");

                                int raceInt = input.nextInt();
                                if (raceInt < 0 || raceInt > 4) {
                                raceBoolean = false;

                                }
                        else{
                                raceBoolean = true;
                            }

                if (raceInt == 1){
                    characterRace = "human";

                    }

                else if (raceInt == 2)
                    characterRace = "elf";

                else if (raceInt == 3)
                    characterRace = "orc";

                else if (raceInt == 4)
                    characterRace = "undead";
                System.out.println(raceInt);

        }
        while (raceBoolean==false);
        }

            finally {

        }



    //ask for character gender
    System.out.println("What will your adventurer's gender be?");
    System.out.println("1. Male");
    System.out.println("2. Female");

    int genderInt = input.nextInt();

    String characterGender = "";

    if (genderInt == 1)
        characterGender = "male";

    else if (genderInt == 2)
        characterGender = "female";

        System.out.println(characterRace);
    //list out character description

    System.out.println("You are " + Name + ", a " + characterGender + " " + characterRace + ".");

    //introduce player to adventure with different introductions for different races

    System.out.print("You came to Glassolin with only ten gold pieces to your name. ");

    if (characterRace.equals("human"))
        System.out.print("Glassolin is home to many humans; some from the far reaches of the realm. You feel right at home, more or less,"
                + " as long as you ignore the occasional odd look from the cityfolk staring at someone dressed in farmer's clothes.");
    else if (characterRace.equals("elf"))
        System.out.print("While an elf isn't the most common sight around town, the locals seem like they don't care one way or another "
                + "about you wandering the streets. ");


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting after:

```
  System.out.println("4. Undead");
```

This code should continue to ask for a valid answer until one is given.

```
//create test to verify validity of race selection  
String characterRace = "";
boolean raceBoolean = false;

Do{
int raceInt = input.nextInt();

    if (raceInt == 1){
        characterRace = "human";
        raceBoolean = true;
        }else{
            if (raceInt == 2){
            characterRace = "elf";
            raceBoolean = true;
            }else{
                if (raceInt == 3){
                characterRace = "orc";
                raceBoolean = true;
                }else{
                    if (raceInt == 4){
                    characterRace = "undead";
                    raceBoolean = true;
                    }else{
                        raceBoolean = false;
                        System.out.println("Nice try. Enter a valid number for one of the four races!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }while(raceBoolean = false)
```

It puts the input inside of a do while statement so it can repeatedly ask for a different input.  Also, I initialized the Boolean as false just as a fail safe.  The while statement at the end tests if a valid input was given.

Testing is done with nested if/else statements.